# FIlter out "class" from REST output json

Tags: rest, atg

ATG version : 10.2
We are having few custom classes as beans.
But, in response JSON, ATG is adding the "class" as following :

```js
"errorCode": "invalidQuery",
    "class": "abc.xyz.RestCustomErrorMap",
    "errorSpcMessage": [
      {
        "value": "2-17410520",
        "class": "abc.xyz.CustomMapType",
        "key": "campaignId"
      },
      {
        "value": "1-3TQ2",
        "class": "abc.xyz.CustomMapType",
        "key": "productId"
      },
```

As given in the documentation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s1902defaultfiltering01.html) I have tried to include the configuration file as

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rest-filtering>

 <component name="abc.xyz.RestCustomErrorMap" default-include="true">
  <property name="class" hidden="true" />
 </component>
 
 <component name="abc.xyz.CustomMapType" default-include="true">
  <property name="class" hidden="true" />
 </component>
 
</rest-filtering>
```

But still not able to filter out the "class" property from response json !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<component name="abc.xyz.RestCustomErrorMap" default-filter="summary">
    <filter id="summary" default-include="false">
        <property name="class" hidden="true" />
    </filter>
</component>
```